# How can I trim the time off the date using regex

Tags: regex, powershell, trim

I'm using regex in the below script to extract the date from a file:

```
Get-Content C:\PROJECTS\Reports\NodeReports\NU_001_20200620.txt |
?{$_ -imatch 'Time Setup'} | %{

if($_ -imatch 'Time Setup'){       
           $Date = ([regex]::Matches($_,'\b\d+') | select value).value -join ','
          
           }
```

The output is coming out like this 2020,06,20,00,50,56  How do I trim the time (,00,50,56) part off to just show the date

Below is some lines from the file I'm extracting data from:

Node 001 Status Report - Report Version 20200505;
Generated 2020-06-20 00:50:56;

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking in a way that will have meaning to a future site user who is scanning a list of search results for a solution. Your current title only contains information already available with the regex tag you added. When you make that edit, also include same content from the file instead of just the filename; it's difficult to say why your expression isn't working when we can't see what it is you're trying to parse.

Comment: Why not just match the format as it is first and then replace the `-`? `[regex]::Match($_,'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}').Value -replace '-',','`.

Comment: if you only want the 1st three parts of that string, this otta do it >>> `('2020,06,20,00,50,56' -split ',')[0, 1, 2] -join '-'` <<< the result is `2020-06-20`.

Comment: Thanks a lot both of those options worked.